# Receiving string over network using recv

Tags: c, networking, tcp, network-programming

I am sending a set of strings over TCP one by one using: `send(sockfd, msg, strlen(msg), 0)` and receiving on server side using:

```
while ((len=recv(fd, buf, MAXLEN, 0)) > 0) {
            buf[len]='\0';
            printf("%s\n", buf);
}
```

Server is printing string random number of times. Sometimes 2 times, sometimes 4 etc. Is this something related to null termination of string? What's wrong?

Comment: what is `rv`? where is it defined and initialized?

Comment: Sorry, that's len not rv.

Comment: What is it printing each time? Is it part of the sent string each time? The main problem may be that you have an incorrect understanding of `send` and `recv`. There is no guarantee that the data sent by each `send` is received by exactly one `recv`. It may take 1 or more `recv` calls to get the entire message and this is something you need to handle.

Comment: Can you show us examples of the actual output and the expected output? Also, I'd suggest removing the `\n` from the `printf` and using a flush instead. You didn't receive a newline, so why print one and make the output confusing with meaningless newlines? (If you want a newline in the output, send it over the TCP connection.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing is wrong. TCP is a stream delivery service. This is expected behavior.

Null termination is unrelated. Even if it's sent through TCP, it's treated the same way as other characters. It's just normal data.

You might need to call `recv` multiple times to receive data sent by a single `send`, and vice versa.

The number of times `recv` is called to receive the data doesn't necessarily have anything to do with the number of times `send` is called. `send` write bytes into the stream. `recv` read bytes from the beginning of the stream.

`recv` reads bytes from buffer space provided by your OS. Similar to reading from a file, but when incoming bytes arrive, them are appended to it. You don't know how many bytes will be delivered. When there is no more data to read, `recv` blocks (unless you use non-blocking socket).